# How to extract 'x' of each tuple in a list and concatenate in python way?

Tags: python

I have a value like this which I extract from NLTK tree.

```
[[('Happy', 'NNP'), ('Mother', 'NNP')], [('Day', 'NNP')], [('Joey', 'NNP'), ('M.', 'NNP'), ('Bing', 'NNP')], [('kind', 'NN')], [('happy', 'JJ'), ('wife', 'NN')], [('mother', 'NN')], [('friend', 'NN')]]
```

I would like the end result to be

```
['Happy Mother','Day','Joey M. Bing','kind','happy wife','mother','friend']
```

How do I do this in python way?

This is what I have done so far, which is very ugly I know. I'm a python virgin.

```
Y = []
for x in X:
    s = ""
    for z in x:
        s += z[0] + " "
    Y.append(s)

print Y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it pretty easily with `zip` and `str.join`.

```
result = [' '.join(zip(*row)[0]) for row in data]
```

`zip(*sequences)[i]` is a common Python idiom for getting the ith value from each sequence (list, tuple, etc.)

It is similar to `[seq[i] for seq in sequences]` but it works even if the sequences are not subscriptable (for example iterators). In Cpython, it may be slightly faster due to using a builtin (though you should always profile if it's important). Also, it returns a tuple instead of a list.

For more information, see [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: why zip has to be used? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: You don't have to use it, but I prefer it.

Answer (score 3):

```
Y = [' '.join(t[0] for t in l) for l in X]
```

Comment: You can replace the inner comprehension with a `zip`.

Comment: yes, but it's unnecessarily inefficient, at least on Python 2 (not a big issue for 2-tuples though)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension:](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> X = [[('Happy', 'NNP'), ('Mother', 'NNP')], [('Day', 'NNP')], [('Joey', 'NNP'), ('M.', 'NNP'), ('Bing', 'NNP')], [('kind', 'NN')], [('happy', 'JJ'), ('wife', 'NN')], [('mother', 'NN')], [('friend', 'NN')]]
>>> Y = [' '.join(z[0] for z in x) for x in X]
>>> Y
['Happy Mother', 'Day', 'Joey M. Bing', 'kind', 'happy wife', 'mother', 'friend']
```